# Full Calendar callback function on time slots selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, callback, fullcalendar

How it is possible to get the times that selected?

In my scenario, I have a calendar that is selectable and the user can select some cells of calendar, then if the selected time becomes less than 3 hours, it will continue and do some action, but if the time difference being more than 3 hours, then it will show an alert message.

> here is a sample but I want to do it before `select` event.

https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/KKKNzRB?editors=0010

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaDay'
    },
    select: function(startDate, endDate) {
      // Find the time diff for checking the druation.
      var fromTime = parseInt(new Date(startDate.format()).getTime()/1000); 
      var toTime = parseInt(new Date(endDate.format()).getTime()/1000);
      var timeDiff = (toTime - fromTime)/3600;  // will give difference in hrs

      // Check if user selected time more than 3 hours then, show the warning.
      if (timeDiff > 3) {
        $('.fc-highlight').css('background', 'red');
      }
      else {
        alert("continue !");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

For better user exprience I want to change the color of the selected part to yellow or red as warning the user. But I didn't know that there is a builtin feature or not.

Fullcalendar v3 and moments.js are used!

Comment: Fullcalendar v3 and moments.js are used!

Comment: yes, but this should be during the selecting process, so when the color becomes red, the user will know and can decrease it.

Comment: yes, it is integrated with Drupal 8, but I think it will not help here as I mentioned just an alert action.

Comment: I think you can probably use [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/selectAllow) for this. I don't think it can do the highlighting, but it does change the mouse cursor symbol and prevent selection when the mouse is moved to an invalid area. I can't make a demo easily right now (I only have access to a mobile device) but I'm fairly sure that would work.

Comment: The Docs say the function must return either true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @ADyson direction I can do this finally.

1-Use [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/selectAllow) for this.

2-change the background-color based on conditions

I try to use direct changes on `.fc-highlight`, but it is not working so I add a class to `#calendar` and make it's back
ground `red` and it works.

```
#calendar.invalid-choice .fc-highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

This is a brief of what I did, but the whole code attached if you like you can check.

```
selectAllow: function(date) {
  if (timeDiff > 3) {
    $('#calendar').addClass('invalid-choice');
  }
  else {
    $('#calendar').removeClass('invalid-choice');      
  }
},
```

DEMO https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/ExxNbMW

```js
            
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('body').append(`<div class="popover fade right in" role="tooltip" id="selected-hours" style="top: 670px; left: 670px; display: none;">
    <div class="popover-data">
    </div>
  </div>`);

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     selectable: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaDay'
    },

    selectAllow: function(date) {
      // Find the time diff for checking the druation.
      var fromTime = new Date(date.start.format()).getTime()/1000; 
      var toTime = new Date(date.end.format()).getTime()/1000;
      var timeDiff = (toTime - fromTime)/3600;  // will give difference in hrs

      var offset = $('body').offset();
      var left = event.pageX;
      var top = event.pageY;
      var theHeight = $('#selected-hours').height();
      $('#selected-hours').show();
      $('#selected-hours .popover-data').html(timeDiff).css({
        'min-width': "20px",
        'text-align': 'center',
      });
      if (timeDiff > 3) {
        $('#calendar').addClass('invalid-choice');
      }
      else {
        $('#calendar').removeClass('invalid-choice');      
      }
      $('#selected-hours').css('left', (left + 'px'));
      $('#selected-hours').css('top', (top - (theHeight / 2)) + 'px');
      $('#selected-hours').css({
        'z-index': '9999',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'display': 'block',
      });
      },
    select: function(startDate, endDate, jsEvent, view, resource) {
       $('#selected-hours').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

#calendar.invalid-choice .fc-highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Full calendar change highlight background during selections</h1>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```